# Conflicting if-statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, ide, ruby-1.8.7, puts

I tried running this code in an online IDE supporting Ruby 1.8.7, and the `elsif` statement isn't being recognized; e.g., if I type in "85", it still returns "Over-Weight".

```
def prompt
 print ">> "
end

puts "Welcome to the Weight-Calc 3000! Enter your weight below!"

prompt; weight = gets.chomp()

if weight > "300" 
 puts "Over-weight"
elsif weight < "100"
 puts "Under-weight"
end
```

However when I run the following, it works just fine:

```
def prompt
 print ">> "
end

puts "Welcome to the Weight-Calc 3000! Enter your weight below!"

prompt; weight = gets.chomp()

if weight > "300" 
 puts "Over-weight"
elsif weight > "100" && weight < "301"
 puts "You're good."
end
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you try to compare strings which are evaluated from left to right, not like numbers.

Convert them to integers (or floats), and compare them.

```
weight = Integer(gets.chomp())

if weight > 300
 puts "Over-weight"
elsif weight < 100
 puts "Under-weight"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

With

```
if weight > "300"
```

you are comparing two strings.

It should be

```
if weight.to_i > 300
```